# PHP curl downloading cookie & javascript protected file

Tags: java, php, curl

I am trying to download the file from the following link
[Desired File](http://www.kse.com.pk/scripts/communicator.php?f=20130812.lis.Z&l=Hd)

When I download it manually it has a closing.lis file as desired. But when I use following curl code it returns a file with 924bytes. If I try to extract it on computer it says file is damaged. But if I click edit in my cuteFTP program it returns following output

> function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) { var exdate = new Date(); exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays); document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString()) + ";path=/"; } function getHostUri() { var loc = document.location; return loc.toString(); } setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', '69.167.137.119', 10); setCookie('DOAReferrer', document.referrer, 10); location.href = getHostUri();This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.

My curl code is as follows

```
$url = "http://www.kse.com.pk/scripts/communicator.php?f=20130812.lis.Z&l=Hd";
$path = "data1/20130812.lis.Z";
$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Later I also tried getting to cookie and run the code but no success. The cookie file when saved has no data.

```
 $path = "data1/20130812.lis.Z";
$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
$ckfile = tempnam ("./", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.kse.com.pk/scripts/communicator.php?f=20130812.lis.Z&l=Hd");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
$ch = curl_init("http://www.kse.com.pk/scripts/communicator.php?f=20130812.lis.Z");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I need to put the above download on cronjob so that it saves the file on the server and I can do rest of the processing

Comment: If it can be done in any other language please do let me know how because I badly need to download this file. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so this code just works:

```
$str = file_get_contents($url);
list($x, $y, $z) = explode("setCookie(", $str);
list($y) = explode(")", $y);
list($z) = explode(")", $z);
list($a[0], $a[1]) = explode(', ', $y);
list($a[2], $a[3]) = explode(', ', $z);
foreach ($a as &$b) {
    $b = trim ($b, "'");
}
$cookie_str = "$a[0]=$a[1]; $a[2]=$a[3]";
$path = "data1/20130812.lis.Z";
$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_str);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Gimme my bounty!!! :D

Comment: Thank you so much! Trying to give you bounty but it says "You may award your bounty in 23 hours". Will check back again to ensure that you get this bounty because you are a real life saver!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `file_get_contents('http://www.kse.com.pk/scripts/communicator.php?f=20130812.lis.Z&l=Hd')`
 to grab the file, and write it on your disk.

But it seems that your file passes by a script which need JS to be enabled.

Comment: I don't know if you can read the extracted using .lis.Z using file_get_contents. I tried saving the output in a variable and printing it out using print_r($data) but nothing happens. The page keeps on refreshing itself.

Comment: alas, the file_get_contents() operation will get you the same contents as the curl usage in the question would. The page requires javascript support so you can't use this simple method to get the file.

Comment: So what is the alternate?